# How to avoid server call using javascript URL routing without large framework?

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, router, client-side

Is it possible to somehow create a browser history urlpath, so that I can make my javascript create and reuse browsercache **WITHOUT** having to route to the server first ?

Link to **/about** = clientside creates the page and use that one, **without** server ever knowing about it.

If it is possible, can anyone please write a simple example that works ?
With no framework..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes it is possible but also need to configure server for the virtual directories ( think about page refreshes, bookmarks etc). There are several client side router libraries you can use. Beyond that asking for code samples is too broad and off-topic as oulined in the [help]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Read about pushState function, for example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API).

Sample code. Suppose http://mozilla.org/foo.html executes the following JavaScript:

```
var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "bar.html");
```

This will cause the URL bar to display http://mozilla.org/bar.html, but won't cause the browser to load bar.html or even check that bar.html exists.

Comment: Oh thanks.. I hope I can after the pushState go to the URL and hit enter on the new URL and avoid the server too..

Comment: I am afraid that if you hit enter, the browser will make request to the server. Because the browser cannot know that it needs to call another page which will generate a new page on the client side

Comment: copy/paste is easy. but this isn't a working example.

Comment: so I cannot hijack the URL path to prevent the servercall ?

Comment: Working example of what? It is not possible to create a "client-side website" which will work without querying to a server at all. History API is meant to give a SPA applications ability to mark their states. So that a user can bookmark a certain URL (produced with pushState), later visit such URL and this is responsibility of your application to restore the state corresponding to this URL.

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for a plugin give [Navigo](https://github.com/krasimir/navigo) a try.